# I decided that my gnupg key I generated is not okay. I removed the ".gnupg" folder which contained it. Is that enough before generating a new key?

Tags: gnupg

I generated my key with `gpg --full-generate-key` then it got placed inside the `HOME` folder's `.gnupg` folder. I removed the entire `.gnupg` folder now. Is that enough if I decide to generate a brand new key? Or do I need to remove data from other location as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the details. I.e. if you imported the key to Thunderbird, then there will be a copy.

But as long as you stick to only use gpg itself, the folder .gnupg is the default and the only store for keys.

BTW, you should know that gpg can handle multiple keys, if you desire.